# Gauge chart using D3

Tags: d3.js, transformation, gauge

I've been trying to build a gauge using d3 and ive managed to hack up something that meets the visual requirements
http://bl.ocks.org/ameyms/9140907

This is however a very very hacky solution since ive positioned the needle by trial and error and the whole thing breaks if height and width are assigned percentage values.
So how do I position it?

Also, how I can make the needle rotate?

Any ideas?

Comment: There're lots of examples for this, e.g. [here](http://codepen.io/jaketrent/pen/eloGk).